# install tripwire without prompts

Tags: bash, debian, installation, tripwire

When installing tripwire on debian, it prompts me if I want to create a site key, local key, and finally, need to click 'ok' when completed.

Is there a way I can install tripwire, not create any keys, and answer the 'ok' at the end?

I'm using Digital Ocean's 'user data' where I copy & paste a bunch of bash commands so I can deploy a new droplet quickly.

Edit:

Looks like I was able to mute them but I still get this:

```
Setting up tripwire (2.4.2.2-4) ...
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/tripwire/site.key’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/tripwire/debian-512mb-nyc2-01-local.key’: No such file or directory
```

How can I avoid the `chmod: cannot access` errors?

Comment: If you simply want to get rid of the error output then you can redirect error channel to `/dev/null`. Please, try e.g. `ls /definitely-non-existing` vs. `ls /definitely-non-existing 2>/dev/null`. (This works for me in bash on cygwin.)

Answer (score 0):

To just suppress the errors redirect the stderr to /dev/null in your userdata script. Or if you want a log of the errors redirect it to a file so you can review upon startup.

```
chmod /etc/tripwire/site.key 2>/dev/null
```

or

```
chmod /etc/tripwire/site.key &>/tmp/chmod.log
```